# Speak with you later

Tags: formality, conversation

As far as I know, it is not common. However, I heard saying "speak with you later" instead of "talk to you later or bye" sounds rather formal and suits business conversations? Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think people only use *talk to you later* in informal speeches, I think people use it because it's the most proper way to say it.

*Speak* is used in sentences such as:

> Do you speak English?
>
> How many languages can he speak?
>
> Does he know how to speak politely?

It may be understood as one hability, or capacity of talking in a specific way: Do you speak informally? - It's an hability of speaking informally.

All what is referred to a language will probably use the verb Speak -

> He speaks very well
>
> He likes to speak English as a beginner so that people will find him funny
>
> He speaks the blind people-language
>
> He speaks formally when delivering a speech.

Maybe *"Speak to you later"* may also be used in a high degree of formality.

Comment: You say "it's the most proper way to say it" - why? according to who? There's no indication as to whether Q or your answer is about American, British, or other form of English. At least in southern BrE, *Speak to you* later is not uncommon - either in person or over the 'phone. I would certainly use it sometimes, but couldn't give any firm explanation as to when I would use either form. I might be more likely to use *Speak ...* if I were intending to, say, confirm an arrangement or follow-up on the current discussion; and use *Talk ...* if the future occasion was merely to be a 'chat', etc..

Comment: @TrevorD - I'm afraid I can't look for any sources in Internet now, as I'm through the mobile app, it would be pretty hard to select some, cut and paste.. I will look for some sources and examples of sentences containing the words Speak and Talk.

Comment: And your answer to my comment that "There's no indication as to whether Q or your answer is about American, British, or other form of English." is what?

Answer (score 1):

It can be somewhat formal and threatening given the context.

If a parent is called into school because their child has misbehaved, the parent may say upon leaving the principal's office

> I will **speak** with your later young man!
>   *I will deal with you when we get home!*

Usually in a business situation, one may want to sound more informal or friendly, so instead of

> **Speak** to you later.

One might use

> Let's **chat** later.
>   Let's **catchup** later.
>   Let's **talk** later.

though "Speak to you later" is perfectly acceptable, similar to "Sincerely yours" at the end of a letter.

"Speak" may carry a heavier feeling than other  descriptions of conversing.  If *someone* has done *something* wrong, one might say

> He has been **spoken** to about that.
>   Should I **speak** to him about that?  *(AmE)*
>   Should I **have a word** with him about that? *(BrE)*

If *someone* says

> Can I **speak** with/to you?

it's often portrayed as *something* serious in the movies, like when a doctor informs a family member of a serious diagnosis.

Another example is, we rarely say

> he **speaks** to himself.
>   *he talks to himself*
>
> He **talks** to himself.
>   He's always **chatting** with himself.

since we're usually on less formal terms with ourselves.